# Jupyter Notebook: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I am getting an error which says "Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>" while doing a project on Jupyter Notebook. I tried to re-install Pandas for resolving it but I am getting this error again and again. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in Advance :)

Code:

```
url_confirmed = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Pranav Jaswal\\Desktop\\COVID-19-master\\csse_covid_19_data\\csse_covid_19_time_series\\time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv')
url_deaths = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Pranav Jaswal\\Desktop\\COVID-19-master\\csse_covid_19_data\\csse_covid_19_time_series\\time_series_covid19_deaths_global.csv')
url_recovered = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Pranav Jaswal\\Desktop\\COVID-19-master\\csse_covid_19_data\\csse_covid_19_time_series\\time_series_covid19_recovered_global.csv')

df_confirmed = pd.read_csv(url_confirmed)
df_deaths = pd.read_csv(url_deaths)
df_recovered = pd.read_csv(url_recovered)
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-652c5d185d63> in <module>
     44 url_recovered = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Pranav Jaswal\\Desktop\\COVID-19-master\\csse_covid_19_data\\csse_covid_19_time_series\\time_series_covid19_recovered_global.csv')
     45 
---> 46 df_confirmed = pd.read_csv(url_confirmed)
     47 df_deaths = pd.read_csv(url_deaths)
     48 df_recovered = pd.read_csv(url_recovered)

~\ananconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    684     kwds_defaults = _refine_defaults_read(
    685         dialect, delimiter, delim_whitespace, engine, sep, defaults={"delimiter": "\t"}
--> 686     )
    687     kwds.update(kwds_defaults)
    688 

~\ananconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    432 
    433     Raises
--> 434     ------
    435     ValueError
    436         If names are not unique or are not ordered (e.g. set).

~\ananconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py in get_filepath_or_buffer(filepath_or_buffer, encoding, compression, mode, storage_options)
    241       Returns the dataclass IOArgs.
    242     """
--> 243     filepath_or_buffer = stringify_path(filepath_or_buffer)
    244 
    245     # handle compression dict

ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass a data frame to read_csv when it expects a file path or open file.

`pd.read_csv` already creates a dataframe from the CSV file. The second step is unnecessary.